# How do I make dots on the slideshow in slick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I'm working on a site, and wanted to add in a slick presentation. I initially had problems, but they are now fixed. Does anyone know how to make dots on the slideshow, along with programmable buttons on the actual slideshow, like the one in [this site?](https://www.theproteinbar.com/)

This is for a brand new site that is not yet up. I haven't tried too much, as I'm quite new to coding, but I've tried using a few other pieces of code I found online (Open use)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sunny Bistro</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Base%20CSS.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.0.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <style>
        .slider-content{
      padding:150px 0;
     }
     .slider-content h2{
      color:red;
     }
      .slider-content p{
       color:green;
     }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="slideshow">
     <div style="background:url(CSS/Images/SunnyBistro-7%20edited.jpg) center no-repeat; background-size:cover;">
         <div class="slider-content">
                <h2> Slider Title 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </p>
            </div>
        </div>
     <div style="background:url(CSS/Images/Gaming-3.jpeg) center no-repeat; background-size:cover;">
            <div class="slider-content">
                <h2> Slider Title 2</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/stickynavbar.js/1.3.4/jquery.stickyNavbar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.header ').stickyNavbar();
     $('#slideshow').slick({
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 500,
            fade: true,
            cssEase: 'linear',
            arrows: true,
            autoplay:true,
            autoplayspeed: 2000,
        });
    })
</script>
</html>
```

I end up with buttons under the slideshow, whereas I would like a set of buttons on the slideshow

Comment: Can you reduce your code to only what is necessary with this issue?
Make it easy to help you, you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to modify the dots placement. I think the class is `.slick-dots`. So something like this:

```
.slick-dots {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: 50px;
}
```

That's most likely not exactly it. But in general you want to use CSS to position the the element on a higher `z-index` and move the dots up. You can even peek at the CSS on the site you referenced is using - do you know how to that? Looks like they are using `transform: translateY(-50)` to move the dots up.

Comment: Do you know how to make the dots actual dots? at the moment, they look like [this](https://i.imgur.com/oZwoEhJ.png)

Comment: @VladConovali sorry, didn't see this at the time. But it looks like you got it answered elsewhere. If my answer helped you though, please accept it as the answer.